# li surrounding <a><img></a> is also clickable..why?

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="www.google.com"><img src="foobar.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="www.google.com"><img src="foobar.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>

li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    width: 500px;
}
img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tirengarfio/7UL3q/2/), on both sides of the images I can click also..why? I just want to be clickable the images.

Comment: Because you set the display to block on your image and therefore it take up the full width of its parent.

Comment: Fun fact: in Opera v12 only the image is clickable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, because you set the display to block on your image it therefore takes up the full width of its parent. That's what block elements do. One way around that is to remove the rules you set on the image tag, and add a `text-align:center` rule to your list item rules.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7UL3q/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your img tag is displayed block. Turn that off to prevent the entire li from being clickable.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are displaying the images as blocks and width will default to the width of the li

Answer (score 0):

On your `img`, you set the `display` to `block`. This means that it will take up the whole line, and nothing else may appear on that line. Because you didn't set a width, this means that the `img` container will take up the whole line. You wrapped the `a` around that, so the whole line will be clickable. Either set a width on your `img`, or take out `display:block`

Answer (score -2):

The anchor tag fills the list item element from left to right. So it is not the list element you click, but it's content, the anchor. Just as normal...